# Audio and soundcard issues in Arch-like system

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, sound-card

I have a recently installed Parabola OS (basically Arch with OpenRC) on my Lenovo 3134A11, and since the beginning I have had no audio in the system. The thing is that when I run `pavucontrol`, the window that opens freezes in "Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait.", and trying any `pactl` variants says "Connection refused".

Seeing this, I went to `alsamixer` to see what's happening. 
I put everything to the maximum and noticed that increasing-decreasing "Rear mic" with loopback enabled causes noise in the speaker. 
So I think that means the system and Alsa recognize the driver;
but I still have no audio.

Here is some general info that I hope may help to illuminate the problem:

Kernel version: 4.20.11-gnu-1

`lspci -v`:

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: Lenovo 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
        Memory at fe600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

`aplay -l`:

```
aplay: device_list:272: no soundcards found...
```

`amixer`:

```
amixer: Mixer attach default error: No such file or directory
```

`sudo aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav`:

```
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1966:(snd1_pcm_direct_parse_open_conf) The field ipc_gid must be a valid group (create group audio)
aplay: main:828: audio open error: Invalid argument
```

("root" user has the same issues)

`` find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd-hda-intel ``:

```
/lib/modules/4.20.11-gnu-1/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko.xz
```

`alsa force-reload`:

```
bash: alsa: command not found
```

`cat /proc/asound/modules`:

```
0 snd_hda_intel
```

`cat /proc/asound/version`:

```
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k4.20.11-gnu-1.
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xfe600000 irq 31
```

Hope that you guys can figure this out!

Comment: It's perfectly acceptable to add your answer as an actual answer, then mark it as accepted. Adding it at the bottom of the question & writing [solved] in the title isn't the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, for some god-knows-why reason, PulseAudio didn't start on startup (that's why running pavucontrol freezes the window either in normal and root, pactl didn't work, etc). After initializing PulseAudio with `pulseaudio --start` it turns out another problem: audio works only in root. 
After a little research I discovered that I can add audio group manually with no issues with `sudo groupadd audio`
(I thought that it has to come "by fabric")
and `sudo gpasswd -a user audio`,
then I just reset and woosh audio.